# Display content from mymodule_page in two regions

Tags: nodes, theming

Is the way, to put mymodule page content in region **content**, and **sidebar** programmatically without using blocks?

ex.

```
function mymodule_page(){
    $page['content']['my'] = array( 
         '#type' => 'markup',
         '#markup' => 'Test', 
          ), 
    $page['sidebar']['item'] = array(
          '#type' => 'markup', 
          '#markup' => 'Test'
       );

 return $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No, not really, that's exactly what blocks are for.** Without blocks, your module would need to send it's content to a region. And module should never need to know what theme you are using. If you would use a theme that doe snot have region you need, you would encounter an error.

Having that said, yes, you theoretically can do it. You would need to replicate what core module Block is doing, so it is way too broad to reliably cover in an answer. You can see Block's code if you want. You will use tens or hundreds times more man-hours to get this done than if you will just create a block with default region, or you will end up with significantly less stable and reliable code, but if it is something you really, really want to try, it is not impossible.

Comment: I have a three page that should generate content for regions ex. gallery. I'm using data supplied by the api. I thought I was able to close it in one function, not in 10 blocks

Comment: @Agrest if your question is not general in nature, but about specific code you are using, post the code, or at least the part that is relevant to the question. In question, of course, not in comments.